# Run Gitlab CI job only once when MR open

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-delivery

I have a scenario in Gitlab where I would like to ping a particular Slack channel when an MR is opened up for the first time in Gitlab. I've attempted to use `rules` for triggering when the source is `merge_request_event` but, unfortunately, this *also* triggers my job when a new commit is pushed to the open MR.

Is it possible to run a Gitlab CI job *once* when the MR is initially opened, and never again after that point, even when new commits are added to the MR?

```
ping:
  stage: .pre
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  script:
    - 'curl to slack url'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case, you wouldn't be able to use GitLab CI/CD because a Merge Request Pipeline is started when a Merge Request is opened, a commit is pushed to the *source branch* of the Merge Request, or if someone hits the Run Pipeline button from the Pipelines tab on a Merge Request.

Those are the only ways to start a Merge Request pipeline, but any of those will always start a pipeline.

Instead of doing this in CI/CD, your best bet is to create a small application that can listen for GitLab Webhooks, and specifically react to Merge Request events where the `action` field is `open`. Here's an example Merge Request Open event from [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#merge-request-events).

```json
{
  "object_kind": "merge_request",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Administrator",
    "username": "root",
    "avatar_url": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=40\u0026d=identicon",
    "email": "admin@example.com"
  },
  "project": {
    "id": 1,
    "name":"Gitlab Test",
    "description":"Aut reprehenderit ut est.",
    "web_url":"http://example.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-test",
    "avatar_url":null,
    "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:gitlabhq/gitlab-test.git",
    "git_http_url":"http://example.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-test.git",
    "namespace":"GitlabHQ",
    "visibility_level":20,
    "path_with_namespace":"gitlabhq/gitlab-test",
    "default_branch":"master",
    "homepage":"http://example.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-test",
    "url":"http://example.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-test.git",
    "ssh_url":"git@example.com:gitlabhq/gitlab-test.git",
    "http_url":"http://example.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-test.git"
  },
  "repository": {
    "name": "Gitlab Test",
    "url": "http://example.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-test.git",
    "description": "Aut reprehenderit ut est.",
    "homepage": "http://example.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-test"
  },
  "object_attributes": {
    "id": 99,
    "target_branch": "master",
    "source_branch": "ms-viewport",
    "source_project_id": 14,
    "author_id": 51,
    "assignee_id": 6,
    "title": "MS-Viewport",
    "created_at": "2013-12-03T17:23:34Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-12-03T17:23:34Z",
    "milestone_id": null,
    "state": "opened",
    "merge_status": "unchecked",
    "target_project_id": 14,
    "iid": 1,
    "description": "",
    "source": {
      "name":"Awesome Project",
      "description":"Aut reprehenderit ut est.",
      "web_url":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project",
      "avatar_url":null,
      "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:awesome_space/awesome_project.git",
      "git_http_url":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project.git",
      "namespace":"Awesome Space",
      "visibility_level":20,
      "path_with_namespace":"awesome_space/awesome_project",
      "default_branch":"master",
      "homepage":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project",
      "url":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project.git",
      "ssh_url":"git@example.com:awesome_space/awesome_project.git",
      "http_url":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project.git"
    },
    "target": {
      "name":"Awesome Project",
      "description":"Aut reprehenderit ut est.",
      "web_url":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project",
      "avatar_url":null,
      "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:awesome_space/awesome_project.git",
      "git_http_url":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project.git",
      "namespace":"Awesome Space",
      "visibility_level":20,
      "path_with_namespace":"awesome_space/awesome_project",
      "default_branch":"master",
      "homepage":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project",
      "url":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project.git",
      "ssh_url":"git@example.com:awesome_space/awesome_project.git",
      "http_url":"http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project.git"
    },
    "last_commit": {
      "id": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "message": "fixed readme",
      "timestamp": "2012-01-03T23:36:29+02:00",
      "url": "http://example.com/awesome_space/awesome_project/commits/da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "author": {
        "name": "GitLab dev user",
        "email": "gitlabdev@dv6700.(none)"
      }
    },
    "work_in_progress": false,
    "url": "http://example.com/diaspora/merge_requests/1",
    "action": "open",
    "assignee": {
      "name": "User1",
      "username": "user1",
      "avatar_url": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=40\u0026d=identicon"
    }
  },
  "labels": [{
    "id": 206,
    "title": "API",
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "project_id": 14,
    "created_at": "2013-12-03T17:15:43Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-12-03T17:15:43Z",
    "template": false,
    "description": "API related issues",
    "type": "ProjectLabel",
    "group_id": 41
  }],
  "changes": {
    "updated_by_id": {
      "previous": null,
      "current": 1
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "previous": "2017-09-15 16:50:55 UTC",
      "current":"2017-09-15 16:52:00 UTC"
    },
    "labels": {
      "previous": [{
        "id": 206,
        "title": "API",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "project_id": 14,
        "created_at": "2013-12-03T17:15:43Z",
        "updated_at": "2013-12-03T17:15:43Z",
        "template": false,
        "description": "API related issues",
        "type": "ProjectLabel",
        "group_id": 41
      }],
      "current": [{
        "id": 205,
        "title": "Platform",
        "color": "#123123",
        "project_id": 14,
        "created_at": "2013-12-03T17:15:43Z",
        "updated_at": "2013-12-03T17:15:43Z",
        "template": false,
        "description": "Platform related issues",
        "type": "ProjectLabel",
        "group_id": 41
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

The key things here for you are the `object_kind` field at the top since this will be `issue`, `merge_request`, `push`, `tag_push`, etc. and we can filter on `merge_request`. Next, the `action` field will tell us what happened with the Merge Request. In this example the value is `open` which means the Merge Request was opened. Other values are `close`, `reopen`, `update`, `approved`,  `unapproved`, and `merge`.

Currently, this is the only way to find out if a Merge Request was opened without the other events that start a Merge Request Pipeline.

Comment: Ah, that's really unfortunate! Thanks for such a thorough answer and alternate solution

Comment: You don't have to create your own app. For example, I use this [one](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook). It is very convenient for receiving and processing webhooks.

Comment: Definitely don't have to, you're right. The app you linked sounds very interesting too!